# DrawGeometry stroke is innacurate

Tags: c#, wpf, render

I am making custom control and it's `Render` looks like this

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext context)
{
    var geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(new Point(0, 0), new [] {
        new LineSegment(new Point(ActualWidth, 0), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point(0, ActualHeight), true),
    }, true) });
    context.DrawGeometry(new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.White, Colors.Black, 90),
        new Pen(Brushes.White, 10), geometry);
    }
```

Why stroke is so *innacurate* ? On screenshot you can see white stroke goes outside of control bounds

[image]

I can't simply clip it with `ClipToBounds`, because I need to draw accurately and was hoping to use stroke instead of having to draw outline manually (figure is much more complex than just rectangle).

I could calculate geometry based on corrected size, yet I have no idea how stroke drawing is calculated.

How to make `DrawGeometry` fit stroke inside control bounds? Or perhaps there is alternative to draw outline to complex-shaped figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Pen is always drawn exactly in the middle of a Geometry's outline. Hence with a Pen that has a Thickness of 10, you would have to create your geometry with a margin of 5 pixels:

```
context.DrawRectangle(
    new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.White, Colors.Black, 90),
    new Pen(Brushes.White, 10),
    new Rect(5, 5, ActualWidth - 10, ActualHeight - 10));
```